# How to do the c# string.split() in oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

How to remove certain words like `DUM` or `PRJ` from begging of string if exists and then split a string   based on character `_` and take the second part .

For example , if we take
`DUM_EI_AO_L_5864_Al Meena Tower` I need to get answer as `AO` and from `EI_AE_L_5864_Al radha Tower` as `AE`

Comment: those all are i checked already and very complicated. i need a simple answer satisfying two conditions i mentioned in question

Comment: Do you want a query or C# code? Have you tried doing this on an oracle query? The question will for sure be answered when you 1. show effort and 2.show what exactly you want with a query example. Once you made your query, your question perhaps boils down to "What is this oracle function in LinQ?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the prefixes you want to remove, then find the index of the first and second underscores and then find the substring between those two separators:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
SELECT 'DUM_EI_AO_L_5864_Al Meena Tower' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EI_AE_L_5864_Al radha Tower' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR( replaced_value, first_separator + 1, second_separator - first_separator - 1 )
         AS second_term
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         replaced_value,
         INSTR( replaced_value, '_', 1, 1 ) AS first_separator,
         INSTR( replaced_value, '_', 1, 2 ) AS second_separator
  FROM   (
    SELECT value,
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               value,
               'PRJ_'
             ),
             'DUM_'
           ) AS replaced_value
    FROM   your_table
  )
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> VALUE                           | SECOND_TERM
> :------------------------------ | :----------
> DUM_EI_AO_L_5864_Al Meena Tower | AO         
> EI_AE_L_5864_Al radha Tower     | AE
> ```

**Query 2**:

You can also use a regular expression:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(DUM_|PRJ_)?.*?_(.*?)_', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS second_term
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> VALUE                           | SECOND_TERM
> :------------------------------ | :----------
> DUM_EI_AO_L_5864_Al Meena Tower | AO         
> EI_AE_L_5864_Al radha Tower     | AE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7b4dde09dfc16573ffc737296dc95df)*